# How would I make it to where if I get the right answer it will print something

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
import random
from browser import timer
operators = ['*', '/', '+', '-']
number = input('How many problems would you like?')
number = int(number)
counter = 1

while counter <= number:
    first = random.randint(0,10)
    second = random.randint(0,10)
    randoperator = random.choice(operators)
    problem = '{} {} {} {}'.format(first, randoperator, second, "=  ")
    answer = input(problem)
    correct = problem
    counter+=1
```

I have tried putting this in but it doesn't run anything

```
if problem == answer:
            print("Correct!")
```

Comment: `problem` is a string like `"5 + 4 = "`. `answer` is a string, for example `"9"`. Why do you expect these two strings to be equal? You need to calculate the expected answer using `first`, `second`, and `randoperator` and compare _that_ with the entered `answer` (converted to an `int` or `float`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to actually do the calculation to find out what the answer is. Here's a quick and dirty way to do that:

```
import random
operators = ['*', '/', '+', '-']
number = input('How many problems would you like?')
number = int(number)
counter = 1

while counter <= number:
    first = random.randint(0,10)
    second = random.randint(0,10)
    randoperator = random.choice(operators)
    problem = '{} {} {}'.format(first, randoperator, second)
    answer = input(problem + ' =  ')
    if eval(problem) == float(answer):
        print("Correct!")
    counter+=1
```

Using `eval` is not a great idea for reasons outlined in the answers to [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1832940/843953) In your case, you already know the two integers and the operator, so finding the expected answer without `eval` is pretty easy. Say you define a function that can do this for you:

```
def arithmetic(op, a, b):
    if op == "+":
        return a + b
    elif op == "-":
        return a - b
    elif op == "*":
        return a * b
    elif op == "/":
        return a / b
```

Then call this function to get the expected answer and compare that with the answer that the user gave,

```
while counter <= number:
    first = random.randint(0,10)
    second = random.randint(0,10)
    randoperator = random.choice(operators)
    problem = '{} {} {}'.format(first, randoperator, second)
    answer = input(problem + ' =  ')
    if arithmetic(randoperator, first, second) == float(answer):
        print("Correct!")
    counter+=1
```

Comment: Even though the use of `eval` in this case seems safe, it's not recommended when other methods of evaluating the expected answer exist. -1 for propagating bad programming practices without including a caveat

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I did say "quick and dirty". This is clearly not critical code and this will work for this purpose.

Comment: what Ted said. I edited your answer to include an alternative solution because it's not at all complicated enough to justify the use of `eval`. Even if this is a benign case where there's _no way_ using `eval` could be unsafe, it's not a great thing to suggest, especially to a beginner, without some context into why.